# I got this error when I compile C file generated from matlab

Tags: c, terminal, compiler-errors

I try to compile C file in terminal, but I got this error

> fatal error: rt_nonfinite.h: No such file or directory

Comment: Way too less information, i would guess that `rt_nonfinite.h` is not present in the include paths.

Comment: Well there is https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/mlc-downloads/downloads/submissions/31296/versions/8/previews/SpectralDP/lib/SpectralDP/html/rt_nonfinite_h.html

Comment: It should be a header present in **MATLAB** and when it is generated, it is left as it is for the user to take care of... But your compiler, who knows where it is, most probably not inside the include directory of **MATLAB**... gives the error, since it does not know where that header is... *You should read the error properly first!...*